# I pushed on the brake pedal it started down, then started pulsating like the antilock systems took over, then they went to the floor not stopping me

Tags: brakes

I pushed on the brake pedal it started down then started pulsating like the antilock brake system took over then they went to the floor not stopping me

Comment: And what happened then? After you stopped do the brakes work? Are there any error codes or warning lights?

Comment: Yes they worked after that, didn't go out again for several days. ABS an break lite are both lit up. I haven't had it hooked up to a code reader